# fields_for is not getting model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, form-for, fields-for

I am trying to start using nested attributes in my rails 4 app. My model is set up like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

and my view is:

```
<%= form_for(:person, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @person.id}) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for(:addresses) do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label :street, "Street" %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field(:street) %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Nearly identical to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Yet my view is not connecting the `builder` form to my `address` model. It is simply rendering the form once.

I also noticed that submitting the data does not provide the params hash as:

```
{
    :person => {
        :name => 'John Doe',
        :addresses_attributes => {
            '0' => {
                :kind  => 'Home',
                :street => '221b Baker Street',
            },
            '1' => {
                :kind => 'Office',
                :street => '31 Spooner Street'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But instead like:

```
{"person"=
  {"name"=>"John Smith", "adresses"=>
    {"street"=>"221 Baker"}
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

PS - the controller... I have tried it with a new object, and one that already exists and has addresses associated with it.

```
def nest
  @person = Person.find(48)

  #@person = Person.new
  #4.times { @person.addresses.build }
end
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your controller (new, create, edit, update or whatever actions).

Comment: I shouldn't need to? – I haven't even gotten to the submission step yet. The view is not rendering the addresses properly (whether that be the 4.times, or when using it to edit an existing `Person`

Comment: Are you rendering that view in `nest` action?, or is it named `nest.html.erb`?

Comment: The view is `nest.html.erb` essentially just a temporary place while I develop. Eventually it will move into a partial etc.

Comment: Can you try changing `form_for :person` to `form_for @person` and see if that results in any difference?

Comment: That's something to look into the route file.  But your form should be good, if you check the logs you should see accurate params hash, with `addresses_attributes`.  Can  you add your route definition to the question?

Comment: If that's all then `update` is a `patch` (`put` in Rails 3) method and you are not allowing that method, hence the error?

Comment: As far as I know `form_for` defaults to `post` method.

Comment: As a test I would just modify `via: [:get, :post]` to `via: [:get, :post, :put]`.  You should look into [`resourceful routing`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) after you fix this issue!

Comment: Are you saying you are getting the same error?  If so can you try adding `resources :people` before the `match...` line.  Also what the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: With that routes, you should not be getting the `undefined method person_path` error.

Comment: This would have been better in a chat :)  Which view is not rendering as expected, the form?  For `addresses_attributes`, can you show your params hash?

Comment: I don't know I even have enough rep for a private chat :(

But the point is that the original question still stands once the code has been changed to `form_for @person` nothing has changed and the params hash is the same as originally posted

Comment: Ran out for errands, came back and tried the routing fix again – now it works! Strange – @vee submit an answer if you want me to mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `form_for` apparently you MUST be using  [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and use `form_for` like this:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
```

Thanks to @vee for pointing it out!